# FormData getting lost in HTTP 302 to 200

Tags: java, jsp, http, http-headers

We getting a SSO request using Ping Identity Federation server which opening target URL with a post of opentoken as form data. But at my application I am getting two request one is 302 Found where I can see form data in headers but after that it issue a 200 request in which data is not there.

Is this normal if yes how to get formdata?

Just curious for this behaviour....I can still access that data from referrer header information.

I am using java/jsp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was actually coming in request body which need to be read using getReader. that's why it redirecting again to 200 as in first request I was consuming parameter instead of body.